# View function is not being called in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a rather obvious security flaw on my website - users can paste a file path into the address bar and download it. I'd rather not have this happen.

The problem is that it does not seem to do be called. User can download any files on the server, regardless of whether pk matches request.user.id or not.

This is the relevant part of my `project/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    #security
    url(r'^media/uploads/(?P<pk>[^/]+)', 'notendur.views.permit'),
    url(r'^media', 'notendur.views.permit'),
)
```

This is the view function that is supposed to check whether the user is the owner of the requested file. I'm including it all to give you as much information as possible.

The code above the hashtags sanitizes the address requested. I know the function is not called because I swapped the `sendfile()` function for a simple `render('forbidden.html')` and nothing happened.

As you can see, th function checks whether the `<pk>` of the link is the same as `request.user.id`, and serves the file if that is the case.

```
def permit(request, pk):
    path = request.path
    path_list = path.split("/")
    s = ""
    for dir in path_list:
        if dir != "media" and path_list.index(dir) > path_list.index("media"):
            s += dir + "/"
    s = s[:-1]  
    # The for loop would add a "/" to the filename. 
    # The system would think the file was a directory, and not a file.

    system_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + s

    if int(request.user.id) == int(pk) and int(request.user.id) >= 1:
        return sendfile(request, system_path)
    else:
        return render_to_response('forbidden.html')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/notendur/list')
```

One very interesting observation I should note is that, when I removed the bottom return statement, `localhost` would no longer refer to `localhost/notendur/list`.

---

---

New models.py:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='files', null=False)

    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=_upload_path)
    user_id = user.primary_key
    options = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.TextField(default=0)

    def get_upload_path(self,filename):
        return "uploads/"+str(self.user.id) + '/' + str(date.today()) + '/' + filename
```

My view

```
View:

    @login_required
    def file(request, filename):
        file = get_object_or_404(File, user=request.user, filename=filename)
        return HttpResponse(open(file.filename, 'rb').read())
```

urls.py:

```
    url(r'^file/(?P<filename>.*)$', 'file', name="file"),
```

Comment: Have you tried putting prints everywhere to find out exactly where it dies?

Comment: I replaced sendfile() with render('forbidden.html'), so if the function is called at all, it should return the if or the else, right? I'll try though. How do I see the output of print statements from Django view functions?

Comment: Are you running production or developer server? Didn't you override /media/ url in nginx?

Comment: I'm only using Apache2

Comment: @Gudmundur To see the output of prints, you just look at the output in the cmd line you're running it from

Comment: Your edit has completely changed the sense of the question you're asking.  You should restore the original content, and either append your addition information, or start a new question.

Comment: ok i'll do that. It has been appended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole approach is flawed.  The check that `request.user.id` the matches the `pk` passed in the url just means that the logged in user's id must match the id they put in the url.

That does not verify that that user is in fact the "owner" of a file.

If user A (id=1) owns `foo.txt` and user B (id=2) owns `bar.txt`, there is nothing to stop user A from accessing `bar.txt` with the following url:

```
/media/bar.txt/2/
```

This code is also particularly unsafe:

```
system_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + s
```

As there is nothing to stop me accessing any file that your server has access to:

```
/media/../settings.py/1/
```

Finally, using the `/media/` directory isn't going to work, because it is not served via a django view at all (except on the development server).  In a real deployment, the `/media/` will generally be served statically.

---

There are a few ways to acheive this.

- Save the data in a django model:

  models.py:

  ```
  class File(models.model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='files', null=False)
      filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
      data = models.BinaryField()
  ```

  views.py:

  ```
  from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

  @login_required
  def file(request, filename):
      file = get_object_or_404(File, user=request.user, filename=filename)
      return HttpResponse(file.data)
  ```
- Save the data in the filesystem, but use a model to track it:

  models.py:

  ```
  class File(models.model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='files', null=False)
      filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
  ```

  views.py:

  ```
  from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

  @login_required
  def file(request, filename):
      file = get_object_or_404(File, user=request.user, filename=filename)
      return HttpResponse(open(file.filename, 'rb').read())
  ```

I'd recommend option 2, as storing lots of binary data in the database like that *might* not be a good idea, but that really depends on a lot of factors.

In either case, you should also be adding `Content-Length` and `Last-Modified` headers to the response, along with the correct mime-type.  I'll leave that as an exercise!

Finally, you need to call this view from your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^file/(?P<filename>.*)$', 'file', name="file")
```

In your template, assuming `my_file` is a `File` object:

```
<a href="{% url file my_file.filename %}">Download</a>
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot!!! But how do I trigger this function? Won't I run into the same problem that the function won't run because the URL contains /media/?

Comment: you will need to post your urls.py

Comment: Ugh, I'm doing something wrong somewhere. Files can still be downloaded freely as before. I'll edit my OP with info

Comment: What module is your view in?  The second argument to url(...) should be the fully qualified path to your view, for example, if your view is in `views.py` in the package `app`, it would be `url(r'^file/(?P<filename>.*)$', 'app.views.file', name="file")`

Comment: Oh, of course. Fixed that. But still, nothing happens. Does it matter that I'm running on localhost? Perhaps this request doesn't go through Django at all, and it doesn't feel like it does. The download pop up window appears instantaneously.

Comment: Also note that I'm putting the filepath into the address bar, not using the template statement you provided.

Comment: And what is that file path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56537/discussion-between-jamie-cockburn-and-gudmundur).